# Не работает Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: iis, ms-access, reporting-services, ssrs

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных MS Access в Misrosoft Reporting Services на веб-сервере с использованием Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. Получаю ошибку следующего содержания:
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

По этой фразе в гугле находится довольно много информации, вот что нашел я:

1. Нужно установить это http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 
   Я устанавливал и это, и версию 2007 года. Разумеется, в битности, совпадающей c установленным на сервере MS Office (в моем примере 32 бит).
2. Нужно разрешить использование 32-битных программ в Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. Это я тоже сделал.
3. Попробовать использовать Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 вместо Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 - пробовал, не помогает.

Результата по-прежнему нет. Я могу подключиться к базе данных, лежащей на сервере, из Visual Studio на своем компьютере. Могу удаленно подключиться к серверу и успешно подключиться из Visual Studio к базе данных (как лежащей на этом компьютере, так и на любом другом).

Но когда я прописываю такую же строку подключения на веб-сервере, я получаю сообщение об ошибке.

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь надо отдельно поставить компоненты провайдера